# Incomplete to difference lists

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I want to convert incomplete lists into difference lists and vice versa.

This is code to convert regular list to difference:

```
reg2diff(L,X-Y):-append(L,Y,X).
```

How do I go the other direction?

Comment: Where did you find that code ? Seems fake to me.

Comment: Assuming you mean by "incomplete list" a **partial list** like `[1,2,3|_]`, there is no way a difference list can represent a partial list unambiguously. Please not that a difference list is not a direct term so it is not a data structure but rather a convention which works for certain cases only.

Comment: you first state that you convert *incomplete* lists to DLs, then you talk about converting *regular* list to DL. Which is it? I assume by incomplete you mean a list with non-instantiated tail, like `[1,2, .... | X], var(X)`.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete to difference list:

```
inc2diff(L,Z):- 
  (  nonvar(L) 
  -> ( L=[_|T] -> inc2diff(T,Z) ; L=[] -> Z=[] )
  ;  L=Z
  ).
```

Use it as

```
23 ?- L=[1,2,3|_],inc2diff(L,X).
L = [1, 2, 3|X].

24 ?- L=[1,2,3|Z],inc2diff(L,X).
L = [1, 2, 3|X],
Z = X.

25 ?- L=[1,2,3],inc2diff(L,X).
L = [1, 2, 3],
X = [].
```

Answer (score -1):

```
| ?- listing(dl_list),dl_list([a,b,c,d|X]-X,L).

% file: ...util.pg

dl_list(A - [], A).

L = [a,b,c,d]
X = []

yes
```